# Do the size of the objective lens of a telescope affect the size of the field of view?

Tags: optics, lenses, telescopes

According to diagrams like this [image: schematic of refractive telescope - Wikipedia]the answer is no, because every part of the objective lens gives the whole image. But when I cover part of the objective lens of my binocular, I only see part of what I see without covering. This shows that the answer to the above is yes.

Answer (score 0):

You have to account for the distance of the  object from the lens. For the objective of a telescope the object is very small so covering it won't affect visuality. But for a binocular, (which is used for short distance) the coverage would affect the visuality. Try yourself by covering your eyes and seeing a nearby object and far away star in night.

Comment: So binoculars work different than the diagram I posted? Everywhere I read that they work the same.

Comment: @GeorgeLee No, it is the distance of the object from the lens. How far was the object (and, are you using just one side of the binocular?).  https://photo.stackexchange.com/ might have an explanation.

Comment: The ray diagram is similar but consider the distance.